# android - pause videoview programmatically at given time

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I need that **VideoView** get paused and **Button** on it get **VISIBLE** state when *videoView.getCurrentPosition()*==SPECIFIC_TIME (for example, 15000 milliseconds).

I've found some solutions using **Timer** or ***postDelayed*** but they're not ok for me because the video is paused when having income call or just having locked a smartphone, but **Timer** goes on and thus the **Button** can appear earlier than I need. Also I've found a solution with ***AsyncTask*** but can't check *videoView.getCurrentPosition()* in ***doInBackground***.

How to solve it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for one solution:

```
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
while (videoView.getCurrentPosition() < (mSec-20)) { //mSec is the stop time
  textView1.setText(getMilliToString(videoView.getCurrentPosition())); 
  // update time display
}
videoView.pause();
```

Another solution is  access the MediaPlayer from the onPrepared method of the VideoView and then set the OnSeekCompleteListener, see code at: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=0wJHWmGpLQFG7RYQLhP1D7VVLLyPl4lNyx1LmVDZMQ1QvRJK12WH!-2094516650?v=T000000092